# Le sens du verbe « foncer »

Tags: sens

> Si tu le penses toujours dans trois ans, **fonce**.

Je trouve ça intéressant, la façon dont ma copine vient d'employer le verbe « foncer », en faisant allusion à un esprit chimérique chez moi. Une pointe d'ironie s'est faite ressentir sur sa voix. Que signifie cette phrase, au juste ? La locution qui me semble s’en rapprocher le plus est :

> Si tu le penses toujours dans trois ans, **ça rigole plus**...

Comment: @suiiurisesse Le tag «sens»???

Comment: @Montéedelait Mais dans ce cas il y en aurait plus d'une. C'est peine perdue. Ça doit être le tag et un truc dans la formulation et la mise en page à la fois. Mais à l'évidence ça ne marche pas.

Answer (score 4):

La phrase pose problème.

On ne peut donc pas dire à quelqu'un de foncer "tout de suite" avec comme condition quelque chose d'incertain, puisque situé dans trois ans. Soit la phrase veut dire qu'il faudra foncer dans trois ans si on continue à le penser à ce moment là, ce dont je doute, soit elle signifie plutôt :

> Si tu es sûr de le penser encore dans trois ans, alors fonce (*go for it*) !

Comment: "*Si tu crois qu'on va se marier pour tes beaux yeux, **vas-y fonce** !*" Come to think of it, can't this be used as a loose equivalent of "*another thinky*"? I mean, on a mocking tone of "*Go ahead, though you're just deluding yourself  into thinking ...*"?

Comment: In the same vein as "*cours toujours*"?

Answer (score 2):

A vrai dire non, ce n'est pas du tout le même sens. Dans la première locution, le sens serait plutôt quelque chose comme "let's go", "don't hesitate".

La seconde locution a plutôt le sens de "it's getting/becoming serious".

Et quant à l'ironie dans la phrase initiale, c'est peut-être plutôt dû au fait qu'elle puisse être moins sûre que toi ou que tu sembles "foncer tête baissée", ce qui signifie ne jamais hésiter quoi qu'il se passe, sans penser aux conséquences. Mais cela relève de l'extrapolation étant donné que je n'étais présent ni dans la conversation ni dans sa tête ^.^

Comment: Je savais pas que “à” faisait partie de la phrase “foncer (à) tête baissée” :O

Comment: C'était une faute d'inattention, c'est corrigé, merci ;)

Comment: Je savais vraiment pas et c’est une nouvelle phrase à moi, du coup merci à TOI pour m’enseigner. ;)

Comment: Ahah c'est normal, nous sommes tous là pour ça et.. "je suis parce que nous sommes tous" ;) (Ubuntu philosophy)